# Size cannot be resloved to a type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to use @size annotation in my spring boot project. The IDE I am using is STS.

But it give me this error.

```
Size cannot be resloved to a type
```

I have this jar file in my class path as well.
I have added the following dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>4.0.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

I have added the required import statement for the annotation:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
```

This import statement is not giving me any error.
But the annotation @size has a red line under it and when I hover over it it says Size cannot be resloved to a type. It was giving me the same error for my @NotNull annotation as well and I right clicked on it and in quick fix I added the import statement for it and the error was gone. But the size annotation is still producing error.

my file:

```
 package com.example.jpa.model;

import javax.persistence.*;



import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post extends AuditModel {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 100)
@Column(unique = true)
private String title;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 250)
private String description;

@NotNull
@Lob
private String content;

// Getters and Setters (Omitted for brevity)
}
```

Kindly help.

Comment: I think you didn't wanted to import `com.sun.istack.NotNull`, but `javax.validation.contstraints.NotNull`

Comment: Remove the dependencies and add `spring-boot-starter-validation` instead. You are using a newer API with an older hibernate-validator. That isn't going to work. Use the starter to get a proper set of dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please elaborate more? I did not quite understand it.

Comment: You are using javax.validation 2.0 with hibernate-validator 4.0 (validation api 1.0). Also you are using Spring bOot (according to your tags). Which has a nice dependency which includes all necessary dependencies with proper versions. \